# Javascript - Is there a clearer way to express "if (a && b || !a && !b)"?

Tags: javascript, math, logical-operators

Would like to express "if both/neither a and/nor b are true", i.e. the boolean values of a and b are the same

Comment: You're looking for `!(a ^ b)`.  `^` is the XOR (exclusive or) operator

Comment: `!!a === !!b` could also be used

Comment: if `(!!a === !!b)` to convert it to a boolean value before comparing

Comment: Except get in the habit of using type aware `===`, rather than the type coercing `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!(a ^ b)` or `!a === !b`:

```js
test(true, true);
test(false, false);
test(true, false);
test(false, 1); // 1 = truthy value
test(false, ""); // "" = falsy value

function test(a, b) {
  console.log(`!(${JSON.stringify(a)} ^ ${JSON.stringify(b)}) => ${!(a ^ b)}`);
  console.log(`!${JSON.stringify(a)} === !${JSON.stringify(b)} => ${!a === !b}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

`^` is the exclusive-or (XOR) operator. It converts its operands to numbers (`true` => `1`, `false` => `0`) and does an XOR on them.

`!a === !b` works because any `!` converts any truthy value to `false` and any falsy value to `true`, and then you can directly compare them.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, but since people aren't used to comparing Boolean results for equality, and because it's a dangerous habit to get into in JS, I like:

```
if (a ? b : !b) {
    ...
}
```